# How to use Format for Julia DashTables

Tags: pandas, dataframe, julia, plotly-dash

I am trying to format numbers in a Julia Dash DataTable so that they are comma separated. However, I cannot get it to work.

```
(name = id_name, id = id_name, format = (locale = (grouping = [3])))
```

I have an example below in python where they use this. Could someone show me a working example?

Source: https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/typing

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='typing_formatting',
        data=df_typing_formatting.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{
            'id': 'city',
            'name': 'City',
            'type': 'text'
        }, {
            'id': 'max',
            'name': u'Max Temperature (˚F)',
            'type': 'numeric',
            'format': Format(
                precision=0,
                scheme=Scheme.fixed,
                symbol=Symbol.yes,
                symbol_suffix=u'˚F'
            ),
            # equivalent manual configuration
            # 'format': {
            #     'locale': {
            #         'symbol': ['', '˚F']
            #     },
            #     'specifier': '$.0f'
            # }
        }, {
            'id': 'max_date',
            'name': 'Max Temperature (Date)',
            'type': 'datetime'
        }, {
            'id': 'min',
            'name': u'Min Temperature (˚F)',
            'type': 'numeric',
            'format': Format(
                nully='N/A',
                precision=0,
                scheme=Scheme.fixed,
                sign=Sign.parantheses,
                symbol=Symbol.yes,
                symbol_suffix=u'˚F'
            ),
            # equivalent manual configuration
            # 'format': {
            #     'locale': {
            #         'symbol': ['', '˚F']
            #     },
            #     'nully': 'N/A'
            #     'specifier': '($.0f'
            # }
            'on_change': {
                'action': 'coerce',
                'failure': 'default'
            },
            'validation': {
                'default': None
            }
        }, {
            'id': 'min_date',
            'name': 'Min Temperature (Date)',
            'type': 'datetime',
            'on_change': {
                'action': 'none'
            }
        }]
```